# How to update UpdatePanel when selected value of dropdown change from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, sqldatasource, dropdown

My drop down are linked with each other and I am using update panel and sqldatasource and I want to update Update Panel when set selected value of drop down from code behind.

```
Protected Sub Admin_ManageUsers_UserListing_new_PreRenderComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ddlStatus.SelectedValue = _Status

        If ddlClients.Items.FindByValue(_Client.ToString()) Is Nothing = False Then
            ddlClients.SelectedValue = _Client
            dsCountries.DataBind()
            upCountry.Update()
        End If
        If ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(_Country.ToString()) Is Nothing = False Then
            ddlCountries.SelectedValue = _Country
            sdsStates.DataBind()
            upStates.Update()
            upStore.Update()
        End If

        If ddlStates.Items.FindByValue(_State.ToString()) Is Nothing = False Then
            ddlStates.SelectedValue = _State
            sdsStates.DataBind()
            upStore.Update()
        End If

        If ddlStore.Items.FindByValue(_Store.ToString()) Is Nothing = False Then
            ddlStore.SelectedValue = _Store
        End If

        If ddlRole.Items.FindByValue(_Role.ToString()) Is Nothing = False Then
            ddlRole.SelectedValue = _Role
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Please help me on this if there are any confusion regarding question then please ask.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do this as follow :-YourUpdatePanelId.Update();

Comment: I have use it but it is not working

Comment: Can you also show your designer code?